# ruby on rails cannot connect to postgresql locally

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ubuntu, postgresql-9.1

I have been trying to set up my ruby on rails dev environment for a project I just started working on. I have installed Ruby 1.9.3, Rails 3.2, and postgresql 9.1.4 on Ubuntu 12, and when I try rake db:create:all I get the message:

```
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:1194:in `initialize': could not connect to server: No such file or directory (NameError)
Is the server running locally and accepting
connections on Unix domain socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
```

I then added:

host: localhost

port: 5432

to my database.yml file, which let me do db:create:all and db:migrate, but when I run the rails server locally it still has the same error.

I have checked that the postgresql server is running, which it is (I also know it is running since rake worked earlier), and have tried a fresh install of postgresql. What might I be missing to make this work?

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure your postgres server is running?
If you do `ps -aef|grep postgres`, you should see something like this:

```
[root@haddock ~]# ps -aef|grep 'postgres'
postgres  5963  5475  0 21:28 ?        00:00:00 /usr/postgresql/bin/postmaster -D <your postgres directory>
postgres  5972  5963  0 21:28 ?        00:00:00 postgres: writer process                          
postgres  5973  5963  0 21:28 ?        00:00:00 postgres: wal writer process                      
postgres  5974  5963  0 21:28 ?        00:00:00 postgres: autovacuum launcher process             
postgres  5975  5963  0 21:28 ?        00:00:00 postgres: stats collector process                 
admin     6750  6607  0 21:30 ttyS0    00:00:00 grep postgres
```

Comment: Also, does your postgres server have the standard config?

Comment: It did have the standard config until a few minutes ago, when I modified it to have unix_socket_directory = '/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432' in postgresql.config after reading http://askubuntu.com/questions/50621/cannot-connect-to-postgresql-on-port-5432 . Also, when I ran ps -aef|grep postgres before changing the config and restarting I had something that looked like that, but now I do not see any processes. Now when running the rails server I get an error saying the connection was refused, and to check that it is running on TCP/IP port 5432

Comment: Did you use the -h localhost option in your postgres config? If not, then you would get the error you mentioned.

Comment: I have reinstalled postgresql and the processes are now running, but I still have the original error. As of right now I have not modified the postgresql config from the default. I can create and migrate my databases for the project, but still cannot connect connect to the DB when running rails server. I thought that using the -h localhost when doing command line psql stuff makes it connect through TCP/IP sockets, is there a config where I need to put it as well? postgresql.config in /etc/? Is there a reason I would want to use TCP/IP instead of UNIX sockets? This is just for my dev setup.